# How to add data to a typedef structure that's nested

Tags: c

So considering I have the following typedef structures:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Subjects
{
    char subjectID;
    char subjectName;
    float marks;
}Subject;

typedef struct Students
{
    char studentID;
    char studentName;
    Subject studentsub;
}Student;
```

I have to use arrays to add the following

```
    Students = {"S1001", "John"};

    Subjects = {
                 {"COS10008", "C-Prog", 65},
                 {"COS10020", "Web", 54}, 
                 {"COS10011", "IBIS", 89}
                };
```

I tried using matrices like so:

```
Student stu[1] = {"S1001", "John"};
Subject sub[3][3] = {
                      {"COS10008", "C-Prog", 65}, 
                      {"COS10020", "Web", 54}, 
                      {"COS10011", "IBIS", 89}
                    };
```

but it didn't work.

I'm supposed to get this output when I run the code:

[image: I'm supposed to get this output when I run the code]

I know how to do it with user input but I don't know how to add the data myself with arrays.

Comment: Your structure types are not well matched to the initializers you present.  Your compiler should be warning you about that.  Did you mean for the various `char` members to instead have type `char *`?  Or maybe `char[x]` for some `x`?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment char to char* conversion is not valid. Use array of character instead.

```
struct Subjects{
  char subjectID[15];
  char subjectName[15];
  float marks;
};

struct Students{
  char studentID[10];
  char studentName[10];
  Subjects studentsub;
 };
```

For initializing and declaring it

```
Subjects Subject [3] = {
           {"COS10008", "C-Prog",65.0}, 
           {"COS10020", "Web", 54.0}, 
           {"COS10011", "IBIS", 89.0}
          };

  Students Student = {"S1001", "John",Subject[3]};
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, but I'm confused what you meant by char to char* is not valid in my original code. Also, can I not use arrays on typdef structures?

Comment: I meant you were assigning a string  "COS10008" to a char.

Comment: `,Subject[3]};` is invalid. `Using typedef` will not compile - `Subject` is a typedef __to an array__ of 3 `struct Subjects` and `Subjects studentsub;` is wrong - there is no typedef `Subjects`. Overall, typedef arrays are __very__ confusing, do not use them.